# How to retrive substring of array elements withought using loop

Tags: java

I have a string array and i want to retrive 15 elements at one shot without using a loop. I'm not sure whether this is possible or not 
here is my code snippet using loop

```
    String8uilder sb= new String8uilder();
   for(int x=0;x<15;x++)
    sb.append(array1[x]);
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Is it possible to access all the 15 elements at once without using a loop?
Consider that array array1 already has 100 elements in it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you intend to do here. If you want to print out the contents of the whole array at once you could use `
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));`, but this only prints the content. If you want to use the Strings in the array in any other way you still have to access the array with an index.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your motivation for trying to do this.  You could use 15 individual statements, but that is a lot of code and is computationally almost identical in terms of time.  How does assuming the array contains 100 elements ease the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained to using an array?  If not, you could use other data structures that let you slice subsets of data out of them (e.g. lists).

If you must use an array, you could create a custom `Iterator` that iterates over a slice of the array:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class WatIterator<A> implements Iterator<A> {

  private int i = 0;
  private final A[] as;
  private final int start;
  private final int count;

  public WatIterator(A[] _as, int _start, int _count) {
    as = _as;
    start = _start;
    count = _count;
  }

  public synchronized boolean hasNext() {
    return (i < count) && (as.length > start + i);
  }

  public synchronized A next() {
    if (hasNext()) {
      A a = as[start + i];
      i = i + 1;
      return a;
    } else {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
  }

  public void remove() {
  }

}
```

But to use it you're still going to have to do some kind of looping or recursion, even if you tuck it away in a `toList` converter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Wat {

  public static <A> List<A> toList(Iterator<A> it) {
    List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      as.add(it.next());
    }
    return as;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] array = new String[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) array[i] = Integer.toString(i);
    WatIterator<String> watIterator = new WatIterator(array,0,15);

    List<String> slice = toList(watIterator);
    System.out.println(slice); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

  }

}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your suggestion i use this approach rather than mine :)